# Android Studio Facebook SDK login failure

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm having an odd problem with Android Studio and the Facebook SDK when I'm trying to run a Facebook login in a fragment but on clicking the login button Android studio displays this error when running the app on my Asus tablet:

V/ContextImpl: ----- packageName = something.something is NOT LOCKED -----

There seems to be very little information on google about this error. Oddly enough the login procedure was originally working, however somewhere down the line it's stopped working and I can't figure out for the life of me what I've changed! I've followed the Facebook SDK guide for android and the issue is still occuring. I've also tried running the app on the Android emulator however it's not throwing any errors, it's not just logging in.

Here is my code for the login procedure:

```
public class Facebook extends Fragment {


private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;

View view;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_facebook, container, false);

    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
       loginButton.setPublishPermissions("publish_actions");

    loginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {

        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

}

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Check the Mainfest, and edit this code :

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"/>

Also check Internet Permission : <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

At Last I suggest you to Change Class name FaceBook to CustomFackBook somje time its happen to conflict with Facebook Code

Comment: Sorry should have included the manifest, I ha e already included those bits. Changing the class name hasn't fixed it btw

Comment: Facebook initialize is one time process so you can put your Facebook defination code  FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create(); into activity part  before setcontentview of Activity

Comment: This is a fragment so I don't believe it has a setContentView

Comment: I mean to say  in activity class before  in OnCreate methodsetcontentview(R.layout.custom_view);

Comment: Oddly enough the same code (with a couple of changes) is working as an activity instead of a fragment

Comment: Solved it! I needed this line of code in my fragment:  loginButton.setFragment(this);